# Can different joint distribution implies different marginal distribution?

Tags: probability

if I have two joint distributions,
$p_{\theta}(x,y)$ and $p_{\theta'}(x,y)$, it is obvious that if $p_{\theta}(x,y)=p_{\theta'}(x,y)$, then we will have the same marginals $p_{\theta}(x)=p_{\theta'}(x)$, can I prove the opposite, that is, if $p_{\theta}(x,y)\neq p_{\theta'}(x,y)$, then $p_{\theta}(x)\neq p_{\theta'}(x)$, and what is the condition for this to hold?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$ be the random variable representing the results of two non-independent coin flips that results in $HH$ and $TT$ with equal probability.

Let $X_2$ be the random variable representing the results of two non-independent coin flips that results in $HT$ and $TH$ with equal probability.

Now consider the marginal probabilities of the first and second coin landing on $H$ or $T$. In both cases, coin 1 and coin 2 land on $H$ and $T$ with probability $1/2$, so the joint density is not unique.

The key here is *independence*. Two events are independent iff $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ (like normal coins). This can be extended to density functions by considering the events of $A = X\in I_Y$ and $B = Y\in I_Y$ for some intervals $I_X$ and $I_Y$. Then independence gives $p_{XY}(x,y) = p_X(x)p_Y(y)$.